# Outlook Redemption Inline Popout Not Popping

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, outlook-2016

I've been using Outlook Redemption's ActiveInlineResponsePopOut method in my application. From feedback I've gotten, the method seems to work fine with most installations of Outlook 2016. However, on certain machines, the method doesn't work (i.e., the mailitem doesn't pop out) and I will get the following exception:

```
>Exception type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>Message: Could not find the toolbar control
>Source: redemption.SafeExplorer
>StackTrace: at Redemption.ISafeExplorer.ActiveInlineResponsePopOut()
```

From what I can gather, it seems the problem started with Outlook 2016 version 16.0.7571. Earlier versions of Outlook 2016 (both 32 and 64 bit) seem to work fine.

Has anyone else also seen this behavior? Is there any work-around?

Comment: When is your code invoked? What is the Outlook language?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for your quick response. The code is written in C#. The method is invoked as follows: after an Explorer.InlineResponse event is fired, a timer is started. When the timer ticks for the first time (after 1000ms), the ActiveInlineResponsePopOut method is called. Let me know if you need anything else.